# python import requests module output 0 1 1.0000

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests
```

In the shell, it's totally fine

but when i try to run a script

```
======================================
0   
1   
1.00000 
=======================================
```

No matter what I type, the shell keep giving me back that thing.

```
>>> 1
======================================
0   
1   
1.00000 
=======================================

>>> 1==1
======================================
0   
1   
1.00000 
=======================================

>>>
```

Comment: Do you have `requests.py` file in working directory? Check it first.

Comment: Also, what does `requests.__file__` print?

Comment: 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\requests-1.2.3-py2.7.egg\\requests\\__init__.pyc'

Comment: I don't have requests.py in working directory

Comment: Add `import sys;print sys.path` before the `import requests` line. What do you see printed?

Comment: ['C:\\Users\\keon\\Dropbox\\pythoncode', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.9.8-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\itsdangerous-0.22-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.7.1-py2.7.egg',

Comment: 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\werkzeug-0.9.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.18-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\requests-1.2.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']